# Running a Docker Image via SSH Github Actions

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

so I'm currently trying to make GitHub Actions/CI SSH into my VPS and run a docker image. Although the main problem is that the job doesn't finish up after running the final command.

This is my YML file:

```yaml
name: SSH & Deploy Image
on:
  workflow_run:
    workflows: ["Timmy Docker Build"]
    branches: [ main ]
    types:
      - completed

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - name: Run Docker CMD
      uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
      with:
        host: ${{ secrets.HOST }}
        username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        port: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        script: |
          docker stop ss-timmy && docker rm ss-timmy
          docker pull spaceturtle0/ss-timmy:latest
          docker run --env-file=Timmy-SchoolSimplified/.env  spaceturtle0/ss-timmy &
```

Regardless of having put the `&` sign at the final script command, the process just hangs until the process is killed. Is there something to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `-d` flag that means `detached` instead `&` sign for last docker command. So full command will be:

```
docker run -d --env-file=Timmy-SchoolSimplified/.env  spaceturtle0/ss-timmy
```